# How to search for a pattern in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, text-search

I couldn't figure out how to search for a pattern in my project or module.

I wanted to find all the files having texts something like `aaabbbccc` or `aaa123ccc`. I see no results found when I tried as `aaa*ccc` by checking Regular Expressions.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.  You want:

```
aaa.*ccc
```

The `*` in regular expressions says match the previous character 0 or more times.

So `aaa*ccc` matches `aaccc` and `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaccc` but not `aaabccc`.

The `.` is "any character" (except new line) and will match `aaaXXXccc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `aaabbbccc|aaa123ccc`.

Comment: Thank You uwolfer, but I actually gave couple of examples, I dont know weather it would be bbb or 123 or xxx or yyy. I want to find out all the occurances of aaaXXXccc where I dont know XXX..